# Custom Pattern for DateTimeFormat Doesn't Work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, zoneddatetime

I have a Rest Controller which has a request param:

```
@RequestParam(required = false) @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'") ZonedDateTime startDate
```

When I Post data into my controller:

```
startDate=2020-12-02T18:07:33.251Z
```

However I get a 400 Bad Request error:

```
2020-12-02 18:20:32.428  WARN 26384 --- [nio-2000-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.ZonedDateTime'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.ZonedDateTime] for value '2020-12-02T18:07:33.251Z'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2020-12-02T18:07:33.251Z]]
```

Comment: Sorry to say, but the 'Z' is missing, should it be that simple...

Comment: @Turo it was a typo at question.

Comment: `'T'` what are those quotes for?

Comment: @fukanchik ISO 8601 defines date and time separated by "T".

Comment: @kamaci I looked again and there's no `'` quotes around `T` in  ISO 8601.

Answer (score 1):

Your date-time string, `2020-12-02T18:07:33.251Z` is already in the default format used by [`ZonedDateTime#parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-).

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String strDateTime = "2020-12-02T18:07:33.251Z";
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime);
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-12-02T18:07:33.251Z
```

It means that you can specify the format, `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME`, which is the default format used by `ZonedDateTime#parse`. Change the annotation as

```
@RequestParam(required = false) @DateTimeFormat(pattern = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME) ZonedDateTime startDate
```

or

```
@RequestParam(required = false) @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME) ZonedDateTime startDate
```

Check the [Spring documentation page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.ISO.html#DATE_TIME) to learn more about the second option.

---

**Some other important notes:**

1. In any case, do not put a single quote around `Z` which stands for `Zulu` and represents date-time at `UTC` (which has a zone-offset of `+00:00` hours); rather, use `X` for zone-offset.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String strDateTime = "2020-12-02T18:07:33.251Z";
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"));
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-12-02T18:07:33.251Z
```

Check [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to learn more about it.

2. This pattern is valid for `SimpleDateFormat` as well.

**Demo:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
        String strDateTime = "2020-12-02T18:07:33.251Z";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
        System.out.println(sdf.parse(strDateTime));
    }
}
```

However, the date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

Comment: Doesn't work. Seems that problem is related to that: DateTimeFormat#pattern -> This pattern follows the original java.text.SimpleDateFormat style, as also supported by Joda-Time, with strict parsing semantics towards overflows (e.g. rejecting a Feb 29 value for a non-leap-year).

Comment: Do you mean "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX" ?

Comment: @kamaci - I've mentioned `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX` as the pattern.

Comment: I still get the exception: 2020-12-02 23:16:18.796  WARN 28932 --- [nio-2000-exec-9] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.ZonedDateTime';

Comment: @kamaci - Try `iso = ISO.DATE_TIME`. I've updated my answer to include this option as well.

Comment: @kamaci - Amidst my tight schedules, I missed to check with you if the updated solution worked for you.